# Is it better to send XMLHttpRequests to different scripts or one master script that delegates tasks?

Tags: php, javascript

I am building a rather larger web application with javascript and PHP. The app has several different types of XMLHttpRequests, and my question is about best practice: is it better to send each of those requests to a different PHP script or to one master script which then goes through and delegates tasks?

Currently I have a requestManager script, but it's getting a bit out of hand. I feel like it's nice to have all of my requests hit that same script first because It's easy for me to debug and remember where my requests are going. The problem is that I'm looking at around 10 if-then statements, and I can imagine that might start to slow things down as it gets bigger and bigger.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The single point of entry to your application should be some kind of router, which directs requests to the correct controller (script in your case). It sounds like you're reinventing the wheel, and poorly. Your router should *not* be a big series of if/else statements; you should store a mapping of URI patterns to controllers and do a single lookup.

You should also be a lot less worried about performance, which *doesn't matter at all*, and more worried about producing a completely unmaintainable piece of code.

If you're truly concerened with best practices, stop what you're doing and build your "rather large" web application with a [PHP framework](http://www.phpframeworks.com/) where routing is done for you.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, and the kind words.

Comment: Actually, sorry about that last comment, I was having a moment. Your answer is good if a bit blunt, and very helpful. This is my first foray into semi-professional development and I do want my code to be maintainable. I was re-inventing, I didn't know how or why, but it certainly seemed broken. Thanks again.

Comment: @eric I'm sorry if it seemed blunt, but it is a constant problem, and a continual source of frustration. Nobody should be starting a new website in PHP without a framework. There is absolutely no reason to build anything from scratch these days, there are so many good foundations available.